# The space of bounded Lipschitz continuous functions is dense in that of bounded uniformly continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

In proving that condition (2) implies condition (3), i.e.,

> Let $S$ be a metric space. A sequence of Borel probability measures $P_1, P_2, \ldots$ on $S$ is said to converge weakly to a Borel probability measure $P$ (denoted $P_{n} \Rightarrow P$) if any of the following equivalent conditions is true (here $\mathrm{E}_{n}$ denotes expectation w.r.t. $P_{n}$, while $\mathrm{E}$ denotes expectation w.r.t. $P$):
>
> - $\mathrm{E}_{n}[f] \rightarrow \mathrm{E}[f]$ for all bounded, continuous functions $f$;
> - $\mathrm{E}_{n}[f] \rightarrow \mathrm{E}[f]$ for all bounded, uniformly continuous functions $f$;
> - $\mathrm{E}_{n}[f] \rightarrow \mathrm{E}[f]$ for all bounded, Lipschitz continuous functions $f$;
> - $\lim \sup \mathrm{E}_{n}[f] \leq \mathrm{E}[f]$ for every upper semi-continuous function $f$ bounded from above;
> - $\lim \inf _{n}[f] \geq \mathrm{E}[f]$ for every lower semi-continuous function $f$ bounded from below;
> - $\lim \sup P_{n}(C) \leq P(C)$ for all closed sets $C$ of space $S$;
> - $\liminf P_{n}(U) \geq P(U)$ for all open sets $U$ of space $S$;
> - $\lim P_{n}(A)=P(A)$ for all [continuity sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_set) $A$ of measure $P$.

I come up with below result

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Then the space of bounded Lipschitz continuous functions is dense in the space of bounded uniformly continuous functions.

I have found a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3379368/1019043) but my proof seems much more simpler. Could you confirm if I made some subtle mistakes?

I post my proof separately as below answer. This allows me to subsequently remove this question from unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$: $X$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ be uniformly continuous and bounded. Let
$$
f_n(x) := \inf_{y\in X}\{f(y)+n\text{d}(x,y)\}.
$$

Let $\alpha >0$ such that $|f(x)| \le \alpha$ for all $x\in X$, so $|f(x)-f(y)| \le 2 \alpha$ for all $x,y\in X$.

It's clear that $-\alpha \le f_n \le f$ is bounded and $n$-Lipschitz continuous. Let's prove that $f_n \to f$ uniformly. Fix $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that $d(x,y)<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$. Then for all $x\in X$, we have

$$
\begin{align}
0\le f(x) - f_n(x) &= f(x)- \inf \{ f(y)+n\text{d}(x,y) \mid y\in X  \} \\
&=  \sup \{ f(x)-f(y)-n\text{d}(x,y) \mid y\in X  \} \\
&=  \sup \{ f(x)-f(y)-n\text{d}(x,y) \mid y\in X \text{ s.t. } d(x,y) \le 2\alpha/n \}.
\end{align}
$$

If $n$ such that $2\alpha/n <\delta$ or equivalently $n>2\alpha/\delta$. Then
$$
f(x) - f_n(x) \le \sup \{ \varepsilon-n\text{d}(x,y) \mid y\in X \text{ s.t. } d(x,y) \le 2\alpha/n \} \le \varepsilon \quad \forall x\in X.
$$

It follows that $\|f-f_n\|_\infty \le \varepsilon$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3377449/the-set-of-lipschitz-continuous-bounded-functions-is-dense-in-the-set-of-bounded/3379368#3379368