# Let $X$ be locally compact and separable. Can we replace $C_c(X)$ with the space of Lipschitz functions with compact supports in weak convergence?

Tags: metric-spaces, weak-convergence, lipschitz-functions, borel-measures

Let $\mu_n, \mu$ be Borel probability measures on a metric space $X$. We have the following equivalence (known as [Portmanteau's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434275/the-space-of-bounded-lipschitz-continuous-functions-is-dense-in-that-of-bounded?rq=1)):

1. $\int f d \mu_n \to \int f d \mu$ for all $f$ bounded continuous.
2. $\int f d \mu_n \to \int f d \mu$ for all $f$ bounded uniformly continuous.
3. $\int f d \mu_n \to \int f d \mu$ for all $f$ bounded Lipschitz continuous.

If $X$ is locally compact and separable, then $\int f d \mu_n \to \int f d \mu$ for all $f$ bounded continuous [IFF](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4570642/1019043) $\int f d \mu_n \to \int f d \mu$ for all $f$ continuous with compact support.

---

I would like to ask if the following statement is true, i.e.,

> Let $X$ be locally compact and separable. Then $\int f d \mu_n \to \int f d \mu$ for all $f$ continuous with compact support IFF $\int f d \mu_n \to \int f d \mu$ for all $f$ Lipschitz continuous with compact support.

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement is actually true. Separability is not necessary here. This is due to the following theorem, i.e.,

> [Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4619138/if-x-d-is-locally-compact-then-operatornamelip-c-x-is-dense-in-ma#4619138) Let $(X, d)$ be a locally compact metric space, Then the space $\operatorname{Lip}_c (X)$ of Lipschitz continuous functions with compact supports is dense (w.r.t. the topology induced by supremum norm) in the space $\mathcal C_c(X)$ of continuous functions with compact supports.